# Is my understanding of the following Rust "reqwest" code correct?

Tags: error-handling, rust, http-get, reqwest

I've been toying around with Rust and have come across the following code:

```
fn request(&url) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
  let mut res = reqwest::get(&url)?;
  let mut body = String::new();
  res.read_to_string(&mut body)?;
  println!("Status: {}", res.status());
  println!("Headers:\n{:#?}", res.headers());
  println!("Body:\n{}", body);
  Ok(())
}
```

---

It is my understanding that:

```
fn request(&url) -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
```

Defines a function that has a single (borrowed) parameter and uses `Result` to handle errors.

```
  let mut res = reqwest::get(&url)?;
```

Defines a mutable variable to store the response object from the `reqwest` crate's `get` method.

```
  let mut body = String::new();
```

Defines a mutable variable to store the responseText string.

```
  res.read_to_string(&mut body)?;
```

This method stores the `responseText` in the `body` variable.

```
  println!("Status: {}", res.status());
  println!("Headers:\n{:#?}", res.headers());
  println!("Body:\n{}", body);
```

Prints three formatted strings (with trailing new lines) containing the response status, headers and body.

```
  Ok(())
```

Handles errors via `Result`..?

---

Questions:

1. What do the empty parenthesis in `Result<()` and `OK(())` mean/do?
2. What is `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`?

Comment: () is both unit type and unit value. Box<dyn std::error::Error> is trait object. Maybe it helps to have keywords to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely correct in your understanding.

1. A Result is an Enum which can either be "Ok" or "Err" - if Ok, then there can be some value of okayness (a result, response, data, output, whatever); similarly, if Err, then there's some concrete error you may want to communicate. With that let's break down the result.

   The should be read like this: `Result<TypeOfValueIfOkay, TypeOfErrorWhenNotOkay>`. These two sub-types can be anything, but they have to be something - can't just ignore it.
2. So if `TypeOfValueIfOkay` has to be something, but if you don't want to return something, you can return an empty [Tuple](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/primitives/tuples.html). That's the `()` in Result. It's just efficiently saying "I return nothing at all when everything goes well".
3. So then the second part `TypeOfErrorWhenNotOkay` can also just be any type - a string, an int, whatever. It helps for the type to implement the `std::error::Error` trait helping callers standardize a bit.

   Returning "some dynamic object but that implements trait `std::error::Error`" requires Rust to know the exact size of this value if it is to return it on the caller's stack (the caller's stack needs to be sized to accept it.)

   This is where the `Box` type comes in - it pushes the actual value onto the heap and holds a pointer to it (which can be of predictable fixed size no matter the actual value on the heap.) The `<dyn std::error::Error>` is an assurance that whatever the boxed value is, it implements the Error trait.
4. So now the final `Ok(())` makes sense. If you read `Ok(value)`: it says the Result enum is variant `Ok` with the value of "empty tuple" `()`, i.e. nothing.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question, I appreciate it. Also, Welcome to StackOverflow!